# microsoft access 2013 option button validation of text box

Tags: validation, ms-access

I am building an Access database. 
I need to validate that a textbox is not Null when an option button equals True.
I usually work with Oracle and my Access skills are limited.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are after, but you can start with this function:

```
Public Function IsValid() As Boolean

    IsValid = Me!YourOptionButton.Value = True And Not IsNull(Me!YourTextBox.Value)

End Function
```